# Loop Java HashMap like Python Dictionary?

Tags: java, python, hashmap, equivalent

In Python, you can have key,value pairs in a dictionary where you can loop through them, as shown below:

```
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

Is there a way to do this with Java HashMaps?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes - for example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
// add entries to the map here

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String k = entry.getKey();
    String v = entry.getValue();
    System.out.printf("%s %s\n", k, v);
}
```

Comment: Comparing this to the Python version reminds me why I gave up Java years ago.

Answer (score 6):

The [HashMap.entrySet()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) will return beans of key value pairs similar to the [dictionary.iteritems()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems). You can then loop through them.

I think is the closest thing to the Python version.

Answer (score 6):

As shown in the answers, there are basically two ways to iterate over a `Map` (let's assume `Map<String, String>` in those examples).

1. Iterate over [`Map#entrySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29):

   ```
   for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
   }
   ```
2. Iterate over [`Map#keySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) and then use [`Map#get()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) to get the value for every key:

   ```
   for (String key : map.keySet()) {
       System.out.println(key + "=" + map.get(key));
   }
   ```

The second one is maybe more readable, but it has a performance cost of unnecessarily calling `get()` on every iteration. One may argument that creating the keyset iterator is less expensive because it doesn't need to take values into account. But believe it or not, the `keySet().iterator()`  creates and uses the **same** iterator as `entrySet().iterator()`. The only difference is that in case of the `keySet()` the `next()` call of the iterator returns `it.next().getKey()` instead of `it.next()`.

The [`AbstractMap#keySet()`'s javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#keySet%28%29) proves this:

> The subclass's iterator method returns a "wrapper object" over this map's `entrySet()` iterator.

The `AbstractMap` source code also proves this. Here's an extract of `keySet()` method (somewhere around line 300 in Java 1.6):

```
public Iterator<K> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<K>() {
        private Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator(); // <-----

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i.hasNext();
        }

        public K next() {
            return i.next().getKey(); // <-----
        }

        public void remove() {
            i.remove();
        }
    };
}
```

---

Note that readability should be preferred over premature optimization, but it's important to have this in mind.

Answer (score 3):

```
Set<Map.Entry> set = d.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry i : set){
  System.out.println(i.getKey().toString() + i.getValue().toString);
}
```

Something like that...

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can do the same like the following.

```
    HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
    h.put("1","one");
    h.put("2","two");
    h.put("3","three");

    for(String key:h.keySet()){
        System.out.println("Key: "+ key + " Value: " + h.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: I didn't do the downvote, but this approach is less efficient than iterating over entryset. The `get()` has an extra cost on every iteration. It's at least not the "right" way to loop through a map. I can imagine that one downvoted because of that, how good your intent also is.

Comment: @BalusC - yes, but creating the MapEntrySet iterator is (most likely) more expensive then creating a set iterator... I doubt, that it's a performance problem, and even if this was less performant, I'd **never ever** try to fix performance issues by *optimizing* for loops like this. (+1 from me, BTW).

Comment: @Andreas_D: The creation of the entryset iterator isn't more expensive. The keyset uses the **same** iterator as the entryset. Also see [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#keySet%28%29): *The subclass's iterator method returns a "wrapper object" over this map's entrySet() iterator.* The source code indeed confirms this: `private Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator(); public K next() { return i.next().getKey(); }`